# Spring Websocket Connection failure

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using spring web socket api to implement Web Socket connection in my application. I have implemented this by extending spring TextWebSocketHandler using the example in the below link.

http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-websocket-integration-example-without-stomp.

It works most of the time. But, the connection stops sometimes, I see the below error where there is conneciton failure.

DEBUG [http-nio-8222-exec-9] [138F0E344FB38D5997135FD3BEF59EC2] 2017-12-06 05:33:44,418  LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java | (62) - Transport error in StandardWebSocketSession[id=20, uri=/connect/app-socket]
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1134)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1074)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:63)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
DEBUG [http-nio-8222-exec-9] [138F0E344FB38D5997135FD3BEF59EC2] 2017-12-06 05:33:44,418  LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java | (70) - StandardWebSocketSession[id=20, uri=/connect/app-socket] closed with CloseStatus[code=1006, reason=null]

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: No. when the connection stops, we are initiating the connection again.